# Connect to WLAN with Java ME

Tags: java-me, wifi

I am programming a Midlet for an old mobile phone (Samsung gt e2120) with the Java ME.
This phone does only support GRPS for accessing the internet, no WLAN or other types of connections.

In areas where GPRS is not available I want to connect the phone to the internet via WLAN for a Http GET request. 
Can I somehow use GRPS or something else to connect to my local WLAN router?

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect WLAN with old mobile phone that without wifi support